# Step by step debugging express server with babel-node

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to be able to step through my express server logic but I am unable to do so.

I am using nodeJS version `v6.2` and babel-node version `v6.9`

This is the bit of code I would like to step through:

```
app.get("/instagram", (req, res) => {
    const instagramEndpoint = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=";
    const limit = 16;
    const user = "testuser";
    const keys = require('./keys.json');
    const accessToken = keys.instagram.accessToken;
    console.log('HIT instagram API');
    fetch(instagramEndpoint + accessToken[user])
        .then(res => {
            if (res.status !== 200) {
                log.error('Instagram API status is not 2XX');
                log.error('Status: ' + res.status);
                return {};
            }
            console.log('request to instagram API successful');
            debugger;
            return res;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            log.error('Instagram API error: ' + err);
            return {};
        });
});
```

These are the commands I have tried and their outputs:

```
$ babel-node --debug-brk --inspect server/server.js 
$ babel-node --debug-brk server/server.js
```

Both of these commands have me this in the terminal:

[image]

```
$ babel-node --inspect --presets babel-preset-es2015 -- server/server.js
$ babel-node --debug --presets babel-preset-es2015 --inspect -- server/server.js  --debug
$ babel-node --debug --presets babel-preset-es2015 --inspect -- server/server.js
```

These commands gave me pretty much this. With `--debug` `Debugger listening on port 5858` was added to the top of the output. I am not sure if my code has reached `debugger`

[image]

When I went to `localhost:5858`, the only output in the browser is

```
Type: connect
V8-Version: 5.0.71.47
Protocol-Version: 1
Embedding-Host: node v6.2.0
Content-Length: 0
```

What am I doing wrong? I cannot step through my `express` server

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you need to use the new attach mode because the code will be transpiled by babel-node first before start debug process.

```
node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js --debug --presets es2015 -- <app_entry_point> --debug
```

After the command run, you should see the port 9229 is listening

[image]

I'm composing the guide on how to debug ES6 in VSCode, you can visit [here](https://vudknguyen.com/2017-07-23-debug-es6-es7-app-in-vs-code/) for more detail